# How to target every second element <p>

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to change background-color in every second p element. But every p element is wraped up with another div class="positions" element. All 5 div class="positions" are included in one div class="bottom-section".

```
<div class="bottom-section">
        <div class="positions position-1 hidden">
            <p class="text-1"></p>
        </div>
        <div class="positions position-2 hidden">
            <p class="text-2 even"></p>
        </div>
```

I've tried to use like seudo class selector but i doesn't work

```
.positions p:nth-child(even) {
background-color: rgba(22, 22, 190, 0.8);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```css
.positions:nth-child(even) p {
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 190, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div class="bottom-section">
  <div class="positions position-1 hidden">
    <p class="text-1">text 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="positions position-2 hidden">
    <p class="text-2 even">text 2</p>
  </div>
    <div class="positions position-1 hidden">
    <p class="text-3">text 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="positions position-2 hidden">
    <p class="text-4 even">text 4</p>
  </div>
    <div class="positions position-1 hidden">
    <p class="text-5">text 5</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply specify a number (2) for every "n" elements like so:
`:nth-child(2n)`

```
.positions:nth-child(2n) p {
  background-color: rgba(22, 22, 190, 0.8);
}
```